# Cachable not found (in EhCache)

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I have the following construct:

```
public List<Integer> getCurrentRoleDetails(){
   return getRoleCached(getCurrentRole());
}

@Cacheable(value = "roleWrite", key = "#role.getRoleId()")
private final List<Integer> getRoleCached(final Role role) {
    System.out.println("role...= " + role.getRoleId());
```

and a configuration

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConf {

    // EhCache based CacheManager, most commonly used in Enterprise
    // applications.
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        final EhcacheCachingProvider provider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider();

        final Map<String, CacheConfiguration<?, ?>> caches = new HashMap<>();
        caches.put("roleWrite", getCache());

        final DefaultConfiguration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration(caches, provider.getDefaultClassLoader());
        return new JCacheCacheManager(provider.getCacheManager(provider.getDefaultURI(), configuration));
    }
    private CacheConfiguration<?, ?> getCache() {
        final ResourcePoolsBuilder res = ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100);
        // Spring does not allow anything else than Objects...
        final CacheConfigurationBuilder<Object, Object> newCacheConfigurationBuilder = CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class, res);
        return newCacheConfigurationBuilder.build();
    }
```

with an entity:

```
@Data // lombok generates the Getter and Setters
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer roleId;
```

But somehow the Cache is never hit. The conclusion arise because I can call `getRoleCached` with the same Role but despite of this the `sysout` prints new lines.

My q: How to specify the `key` properly to get the desired result?

**UPDATE:** After the hint I figured out that the `public` methods are called via Spring proxy while the internal (of a class) is called directly. When calling directly there is not any further interception from Spring done ==> the `Cache` will not be checked, i.e. not applied. Refactoring and moving the requested method fixed my prob.

Answer (score 1):

@Cacheable is use spring aop proxy, so you can not use @Cacheable on private method. try public method

Comment: `public` does not help - neither does removing the `final`

Comment: i write a sample as same as your code.  it's work well.    https://github.com/luolibing/coding-life/tree/master/modules/ehcache

Comment: After testing and further investigation in the code I figured out what the _real_ problem is/was. I guess it is the similar problem like your code: `invokePrivate()` does not have a parameter `role` - nevertheless you set the key - which is unlogic. I have the problem the other way - as updated my q. Anyway I have now a better understanding about the mechanism. Thx!